# reversing a string in c without library function

Tags: c, string, reverse

In this program I am trying to take a string as input from the user guessing that the maximum length of the string here is 40 (obviously can exceed).

I'm finding out the length and using the length to create another character array dynamically( only to prevent assigning this array with any random value) and finally, adding the characters from the last to get the reversed string.

It compiles just fine, but upon running, provides no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char word[40];
    char *rev;
    int i=0;
    int l=0;
    printf("Enter any statement \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", word);
    while(word[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    // i contains  the length of the string
    rev=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
    while(i>0)
    {
        rev[l]=word[i];
        i--;
        l++;
    }
    printf("\n %s", rev);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you compute the length of the string in `i`, then `word[i]` points to the terminating null. You are then copying that to the first character position of your reversed string. So your answer is coming up "empty".

Comment: For a simple program like this, *use the debugger*! Step through the code, line by line, to see what really happens.

Comment: ... and for more complicated programs a debugger if also very helpful of course ;-)

Comment: `malloc` is a library function...

Answer (score 3):

You have two (at least) problems: The first one is that you swap characters *twice*. The second problem is that you also include the terminator character in your swapping.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a 'one-off' type error and are not seeing any output because the teminating `\0` character is being copied to the first position of `rev`.

Comment: Do you mean terminating `\0`?

Answer (score 1):

`rev[l]=word[i];` should `rev[l]=word[i-1];`

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1:-**

**In C a string is always ended with `'\0'`**(NULL Termination),you should always manually insert a `'\0'` at the end,which i think you forgot.But no worries even i did not remember it as well when i started...:) ,Experiences like these will make you from next time.

**Point 2:-**

Assume you have a string `char str[]="ABCD" ;`,In memory this would look like this

```
   ------------IN Memory----------------
  | 'A' || 'B' || 'C' | | 'D' | | '\0' |      
   -------------------------------------
     0      1      2       3        4
```

Just by looking we can say that its **length would be 4** *(we know that we don't include `'\0'` when calculating length)*. For copying in reverse we need to start with character `'D'` **whose index is 3**,that means you have to start copying from 2nd last character whose index can be can be found from  **length of string -1**.The mistake you did in your above program is you have used length of string (which is 4), to start copying.which copies `'\0'` as first character in `rev[]` ,Hence it provides no output.

**Other points:-**

Based on the above two points i have corrected the mistakes, see comments in the below program to understand it well.And i have used `int j;`instead of `int l;` because i felt so confusing.
and please **use width specifier when reading strings using `scanf();`** In your while loop,**you should change the condition from `i>0` to `i>=0`** because when `i` reaches 0,`i>0` condition will break the loop before copying the first character from `word[]` to `rev[]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char word[40];
   char *rev;
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   printf("Enter any statement \n");
   scanf("%39[^\n]", word);//using width specifier,(POINT 1)here 39 because sizeof(word)-1, one left to accommodate '\0' at end.

    while(word[i]!='\0')//calculating length of string
    {
       i++;
    }
    rev=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char)+1);// (POINT 1),here making +1 to accommodate '\0' at end.

    i=i-1;//(POINT 2)- Last index of the array is always length of string - 1

   while(i>=0)//This should be i>=0 because you also want to copy first character of input string.
   {
       rev[j]=word[i];
       i--;
       j++;
   }
   rev[j]='\0';//(POINT 1) You should end with '\0'.
   printf("\n %s", rev);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf format string looks weird. Perhaps you are using some strange feature of it that I'm unaware of, so I'll pass on that. But you need to make sure that `word` is a null terminated string after the user input is done.

```
while(word[i]!='\0')
```

This loops counts *until* it finds the null term. So `i` will contain the string length: you just invented the strlen() function. It will not contain the string length plus the null terminator length (1).

Therefore

```
rev=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
```

is incorrect, you need to allocate i+1 bytes.

Also, you shouldn't cast the result of malloc, because doing so is completely pointless.

And when you copy, you have to ensure that you also copy the null terminator.

Comment: oh, scanf("%[^\n]", word) takes input of the array inclusive of the blank spaces and terminates the array only after it reaches a new line. And yes, doing as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The code has several memory mistakes and using static memory is also an issue. But for if you are using for practice purpose below are the changes and its explanation.

```
i--; // you can't place a '\0' to your rev[0] else it would always be NULL string when you print
while(i>=0)
{
    rev[l]=word[i];
    i--;
    l++;
}
    rev[l]='\0'; // string should be terminated by '\0'
printf("\n%s\n", rev);
```

Comment: @user3396254 - can you paste the result in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below code with just one modification should return just correct answer. I changed in 2nd while loop from:

rev[l]=word[i];

to

rev[l]=word[i-1];

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char word[40];
    char *rev;
    int i=0;
    int l=0;
    printf("Enter any statement \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", word);
    while(word[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    // i contains  the length of the string
    rev=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
    while(i>0)
    {
        rev[l]=word[i-1];
        i--;
        l++;
    }
    printf("\n %s", rev);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Reverse of a string without using string functions 

 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 void main()
  {
  char a[40];
  int j=0,len=0;
  clrscr();
  printf("please enter your name\n");
  gets(a);              // takes white spaces as characters
  printf("the reverse of your name is\n");
  while (a[j]!=NULL)    // finding the length of the string array
   {
    len++;
    j++;
   }
  for(int k=len;k>=0;k--) 
   {
    printf("%c",a[k]);
   }
  getch();
 }
```

Output - please enter your name

```
     dwayne rock johnson 

     the reverse of your name is

     nosnhoj kcor enyawd
```

Answer (score -3):

As noted, array indices begin at zero and end at length-1.  Moreover, if you like, you could rewrite your code in a more cryptic fashion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char word[40];
  char *rev;
  int i=0;
  int l=0;
  printf("Enter any statement \n");
  scanf("%[^\n]", word);

  while(word[++i]);

  // i contains  the length of the string 
  rev=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
  while(rev[l++]=word[i---1], i>0);
  printf("%s\n", rev);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this please, `word[i---1];` You have undefined behavior in your code, here: `while(word[++i]);`, clear > clever.

Comment: All you did was to clutter down some pretty nicely written code with bad coding practice, without actually fixing any of the bugs. How exactly does this answer the question?

Comment: @self : are you sure `word[i---1]` is UB ? I think not, but it's admittedly ugly.

Comment: @self. That's not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin It most certainly is.

Comment: @self. Is too! Is not! Mooom! C11 6.5/2 `If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.`. Since `word` and `i` are not the same object, that does not apply. Further `If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.` But there are no multiple allowable orderings here either. So no UB.

Comment: @self. So quote the standard and enlighten us why it is.

Comment: @Lundin You don't check the first element in the array.

Comment: @self. That's a typical _application bug_ caused by bad programming. It is not undefined behavior, as defined by the C standard. Unless of course you read out of bounds of the array because of the bug.

Comment: @Lundin If the input is empty from scanf( user input is only enter ), the loop will read out of bounds since the null terminator is skipped, therefore causing UB. qed Locals vars are not initialized to 0.

Comment: @Lundin Furthermore, any naive use of scanf function will make any code manifest UB, because you can always write out of bounds; You would have to restrict the size with length specifier.

Comment: @Roberto, this code works just fine but I don't understand the working behind
while(rev[l++]=word[i---1], i>0);

Comment: It's just an admittedly cryptical and less-than-ideal way of writing  while(word[i-1] != '\0' && i>0) { rev[l]=word[i-1]; l++; i--; }.  The "trick" is in applying the rules on precedence and associativity of operators.